# I have this Dataset, I want to convert it into this New Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis, stock

[This is my Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKvV.png)

[Expected Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d3Ws.png)

This is just a Demo Dataset, I have a large dataset with millions of rows, I want to classify my shares as share bought and sold for every row, if the type is P it should be added in the column of bought and vice versa, similarly, if a row is empty it should just enter 0 in those two columns. Please suggest something without any loops as it's a pretty huge dataset.
The Dataset is almost for millions of rows, so we need something proper which will be directly applicable for dataset.

Only For loop has been tried, but takes too much time.

Comment: `pivot` ID/Type/Quantity, then `join` to the original

Comment: @mozway can you please suggest a small code example here?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input (not an image)?

Comment: Yes, sure, I have pasted it here, please provide a code.
link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hXBaSGNdk_0cXgBowQsIl7U92DyTBbS5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @mozway can you please do it, I have pasted the link here, it's kind of urgent too, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but **urgent** is not a concern here, this is **NOT** a free coding service, rather a platform to help the community. If you're on a deadline, hire a professional. That said, what you need is `out = df.join(df.assign(Type=df['Type'].map({'P': 'Purchased', 'S': 'Sold'})).pivot(columns='Type', values='Quantity'))`